# Tuleap LDAP plugin installation

Tags: installation, ldap, tuleap

I have installed the ldap plugin in Tuleap 7.2.99.22, configure it with the following ldap.inc, activate it and turn to "ldap" the $sys_auth_type in /etc/codendi/conf/local.inc.

> $sys_ldap_server = "ldap://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxx";
>
> $sys_ldap_dn = "OU=xxxxx xxx,DC=xxxx,DC=corp";
>
> $sys_ldap_bind_dn = "CN=xxxx,OU=Projects,OU=xxxxx (xx xx),OU=xxxxx xxx,DC=xxxx,DC=corp";
>
> $sys_ldap_bind_passwd = "xxxxxx";
>
> $sys_ldap_uid   = "sAMAccountName";
>
> $sys_ldap_eduid = "sAMAccountName";
>
> $sys_ldap_cn    = "cn";
>
> $sys_ldap_mail  = "mail";
>
> $sys_ldap_people_dn = "OU=Users,OU=xxxxx (xx xx),OU=xxxxx xxx,DC=xxxx,DC=corp";
>
> $sys_ldap_search_user="(|(sAMAccountname=%words%)(cn=%words%)(mail=%words%))";
>
> $sys_ldap_tooltip_search_user='(&(|(sn=%words%*) (cn=%words%*)(department=%words%*) (givenName=%words%*)(sAMAccountname=%words%*))(!(givenName=BoiteVocale))(sAMAccountname=*))';
>
> $sys_ldap_tooltip_search_attrs='sAMAccountname;sn;givenName;cn;name;displayName;department';
>
> $sys_ldap_default_user_status = 'A';
>
> $sys_ldap_svn_auth = 1;
>
> $sys_ldap_daily_sync = 0;
>
> $sys_ldap_daily_sync_retention_period = '';
>
> $sys_ldap_user_management = 1;
>
> $sys_ldap_grp_enabled   = 0;
>
> $sys_ldap_grp_dn        = 'ou=groups,dc=tuleap,dc=net';
>
> $sys_ldap_grp_cn        = 'cn';
>
> $sys_ldap_grp_member    = 'uniquemember';

I have verified that the command ldapsearch is valid with the element that I have put in the ldap.inc file, but there is nothing special in Tuleap. I have tried to connect with an account of the LDAP and I have the following message : "Invalid Password Or User Name".

1. Is there any log that can help me to find where is the problem ?
2. Is there anything to do after the plugin installation in order to collect all the ldap user in Tuleap ? Is there a command to do that ?
3. If I have a local user with the same login than in the LDAP, what will happen ?

Thanks for any answers that could help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `tail -f /var/log/codendi/codendi_syslog` should give you logs.
2. You need to log-in to the platform as admin then go to Plugins Administration and check the ldap plugin is both installed and active. There is no comammand to 'import' all ldap users. All ldap users should be able to log-in with their usual user/pass and they will need to configure a certain amount of things on their first log-in (e.g. timezone)
3. I'm not sure. It's possible one will take precedence over the other; it's possible neither of them will be able to log-in.

Note that your `$sys_ldap_grp_dn` is most probably wrong. Note also that your Tuleap version is pretty old.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since I have updated Tuleap with the latest version, everything works fine.